# Reinicializar DataTable Jqery

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo un `DataTable` creado inicialmente con `Html`

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tablaParametrosMatricesSeleccionadas">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-sm-4">Cuenta</th>
          <th class="col-sm-5">Nombre</th>
          <th class="col-sm-3">Acci&oacute;n</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="listadoMatriz">                                    
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

El problema surge al querer crear otra Tabla por `JS` en el mismo espacio de ese `datatable` (me refiero a cambiar la cantidad de celdas, títulos, e información)

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, si puedes acomodarla un poco para que podamos entenderla sería genial, también, agrégale más información sobre el código.

Comment: En el sitio web de dataTable explican como tener dos o mas tablas en un mismo espacio, lo que entiendo es que de primera intencion muestras cierta informacion, y haciendo alguna accion traes mas datos y columnas, a lo mejor seria mas conveniente que generes la tabla completa con todas las columnas y rellenar los segun vayas necesitando o actualizando, se veria bastante dinamico

Comment: No se entiende, eso es una tabla html... donde está el js de datatable? y cuál es el problema puntualmente? agrega cómo haces eso de " crear otra Tabla por JS en el mismo espacio de ese datatable"

Comment: @Cesarin Tienes el link ?

Comment: @BrayamValero No me deja colocar el codigo de Js, me dice que hay un error o que algo le falta para poder ponerlo como codigo :c

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Claro, cuando me refiero a poner otra tabla, me refiero a que con cada select genere una tabla diferente con X valores desde un servicio POST

Comment: Aqui hay un tema parecido: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/44593/incluir-una-tabla-dentro-de-otra

Comment: @Cesarin La verdad es que puedo generar una tabla dentro de otra, pero lo que no puedo hacer, es generar una nueva tabla en lugar de la existente (inicializada por html)

Comment: @JuanPablo No entiendo muy bien lo que intentas hacer, te sugeria en un principio que a lo mejor era mas practico colocar la tabla completa, aunque no trajera todos los datos, y despues de alguna accion cargar los datos que faltan como una especie de actualizar la tabla se vería muy vistoso, si no lo mas practico es cargar la tabla completa en otra vista, un modal , en una ventana nueva...